# What is the ratio between the edge of this pyramids base compared to the pyramids height? Please

Tags: geometry, logarithms

A sphere that has the radius of 1 has a right angle square based pyramid inside it with the maximum volume possible. What is the ratio between the edge of the pyramids base compared to the pyramids height? How do I find out the edge and the height, explanations please. Thank you.

Comment: What work have you already done on this question? We are not here to blindly answer your questions but we can help if you show us where exactly you are stuck

Comment: @lioness99a I just don't know where to start with this question when first figuring out where the base of this pyramid lies on the circle.

Comment: The answer is $\sqrt3$ for the ratio.  Show some effort, please. Interesting problem, by the way.

Comment: @johkuu Welcome to MSE. Why did you pose the same question here again? Did you go through the comments and answers to your earlier post, which has been closed now because you have failed to provide additional details and clarity?